# Canvas does not appear multiple times even though I call it multiple times

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I have this javascript for a canvas (this is not all of it)

```
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
let labels = ['Banking', 'Finances', 'Shopping', 'Recreation', 'Healthcare', 'Transportation', 'Food and Drink'];
let colorHex = ['#FB3640', '#86A9C5', '#286CA1', '#77FAC', '#1C203D', '#798E9C', '#2A303D'];
```

I call it in an html (as shown below)

```
   <div class="Stuff">
    
    <div class="Translucent-Box">
      <h1 class="Box-Header">Categorical Spending Left</h1>
      <canvas id="myChart" height="250" width="250"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div class="Translucent-Box">
      <h1 class="Box-Header">Categorical Spending Center</h1>
      <canvas id="myChart" height="250" width="250"></canvas>
    </div>  

    <div class="Translucent-Box">
      <h1 class="Box-Header">Categorical Spending Right</h1>
      <canvas id="myChart" height="250" width="250"></canvas>
    </div>

   </div>
```

However my javascript (chart) only appears once. This problem has been driving me crazy for a few hours now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should not be using more than one ID in your page with the same name, IDs should be unique. MDN: *The id global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document*

Comment: If I copy the javascript file and change the first line to let "ctx = document.getElementById('StackOverflow').getContext('2d');" and then change the corresponding div. I still dont get two graphs.

Comment: This line here in each of your canvas elements... `id="myChart"` This should not be the same in each element, I suggest changing this to a class then query with querySelectorAll() and run a JS for or forEach loop on the nodeList.

Comment: @dalelandry I changed the original code to document.getElementByClassName('myChart') and now none of them appear

Comment: Its actually `getElementsByClassName()` *elements* with an ***s***, also you will have to access the index of each element within a for loop if you use a HTML Collection list. You can also use `querySelectorAll('.myChart")` which will return a nodeList that acts like an array where forEach loop can be used.